# OSGI kafka client bundle causes a framework exception due to missing constraint

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, osgi

Subject : OSGI Kafka client bundle causes a framework exception due to missing constraint

I downloaded the `kafka-clients` OSGI bundle (org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients-0.11.0.1_1.jar) from Apache ServiceMix (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients/0.11.0.1_1).

Below is my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.0.1_1</version>
</dependency>
```

I used this to develop my Kafka producer code within the `sflow_collector` module of my application built using OSGI.
Everything compiles, no issue there.

When I run my application, I get the following error during the loading of the `sflow_collector` module.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "sflow-collector_1.0.0 [49]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer; version="[0.11.0,1.0.0)"
```

I checked the manifest of the Kafka OSGI bundle, it looks fine. I see the producer in the export list (shown in bold below).

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1508749231115
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_111
Built-By: jbonofre
Bundle-Description: This OSGi bundle wraps kafka-clients 0.11.0.1 jar file.
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: kafka-clients
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Version: 0.11.0.1_1
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package:
    org.apache.kafka.clients;version="0.11.0.1";uses:="org.apache.kafka.common,
    org.apache.kafka.common.config,
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors,
    org.apache.kafka.common.internals,
    org.apache.kafka.common.metrics,
    org.apache.kafka.common.network,
    org.apache.kafka.common.protocol,
    org.apache.kafka.common.requests,
    org.apache.kafka.common.utils",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.admin;version="0.11.0.1";
    uses:="org.apache.kafka.common,
    org.apache.kafka.common.acl,
    org.apache.kafka.common.annotation,
    org.apache.kafka.common.config,
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors",    
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer;version="0.11.0.1";
    uses:="org.apache.kafka.clients.coumer.internals,
    org.apache.kafka.common,
    org.apache.kafka.common.config,
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors,
    org.apache.kafka.common.header,
    org.apache.kafka.common.record,
    org.apache.kafka.common.serialization",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals;version="0.11.0.1";uses:="org.apache.kafka.clients,
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer,
    org.apache.kafka.common,
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors,
    org.apache.kafka.common.metrics,
    org.apache.kafka.common.protocol,
    org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types,
    org.apache.kafka.common.requests,
    org.apache.kafka.common.serialization,
    org.apache.kafka.common.utils",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.producer;version="0.11.0.1";uses:="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer,
    org.apache.kafka.common,
    org.apache.kafka.common.config,
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors,
```

I am not able to fix this problem.

Any help much appreciated. Please email is any more info is required.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably understood, the error message

> Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer; version="[0.11.0,1.0.0)

.. indicates that a bundle (probably your bundle) imports the 'clients.producer' package, while no bundle in the container exports that package with the given version. The version matches the kafka-clients bundle manifest that you pasted, so no problem there. My guess is that the kafka-clients bundle is not deployed in the container, and you have to deploy it as well as your own bundle.

Which container are you using? If it's Apache Karaf you might find some hints in [this github project](https://github.com/robgmills/zero-downtime-soa).

Comment: Hi. Okay I'll have to see how to deploy the bundle then. I'll investigate. thanks for the help.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link that could be helpful if you use Apache Karaf as you OSGi container.